# Position 'anchor' in same place over image at all breakpoints

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position the anchor 'Link' in the centre of the red section of the image at all times (all breakpoints). Here I have set the position: absolute; and adjusted it to be perfect.

However if I was add more text to the 'paragraph section' or adjust the current breakpoint, the position of this link would move. I put all my code on CodePen here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PrVQgm?editors=1100

Hard positioning as below;

```
  .hero-hub-image .btn-tertiary {
    left: 175px;
    top: 120px; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying position element on fluid background image you have to use fluid units, so try use calc() function with %units to best fit your elements, e.g.

`left: calc(15% + 100px);`